CLion standard C++ header files not found after IDE version upgrade on macOS
Note: This is NOT a duplicate of CLion C++ header files not found after macOS is updated to Catalina

CLion is reporting all header files to be missing in my lone C++ project
#include <cstdio>
⌃⌃⌃⌃⌃⌃⌃⌃⌃⌃⌃⌃⌃⌃⌃⌃⌃

'cstdio' file not found

It was working all right until last week and the problem started appearing after I upgraded from v2024.1.5 to v2024.2.2 via JetBrains ToolBox.

UPDATE
The same thing happened when I installed an XCode update on my Mac. (and the same resolution given below worked)

What have I tried?

Build > Rebuild Project

Tools > CMake > Reload CMake Project as suggested here

CLion > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > CMake > Manage toolchains... > OK as suggested here


How can I go about fixing it?

I'm on

CLion 2024.2.2 Build #CL-242.22855.75
macOS Sonoma 14.6.1, Chip Apple M1 Pro, Memory 32 GB


The good old 'reset cache' thing fixed it for me!
Tools > CMake > Reset Cache and Reload Project
